# How to check the innerformgroup status im angular reactive form

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a formgroup named as productForm and inner formgroupName   productInnerForm.i can able to see outer form group status and value.
by using below markup

```
{{productForm.status | json}}
```

```
{{productForm.value | json}}
```

when i have tried with innerformgroup status getting error.

```
<pre>{{productForm.productInnerForm.status | json}}</pre>
 <pre>{{productForm.productInnerForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

In component also getting undefined.
`this.productForm.get('productInnerForm').valid` which shows undefined.

outer form status is working as expected.

```
this.productForm.valid;
```

**in component.ts**

```
constructor(public formBuilder : FormBuilder){
}
```

productForm:FormGroup;

```
 this.productForm= this.formBuilder.group({
              ProductIDCtrl: '',
           productInnerForm: this.formBuilder.group({
                ProductNameCtrl:[''],
                ProductSUKCtrl:[''],
                ProductStatusCtrl:[''],
                ProductTypeCtrl:['']

              })
            });

    --------------------------------

        <form [formGroup]="productForm" class="secondary-search">

                        <input type="text" formControlName="ProductIDCtrl">


                        <div formGroupName="productInnerForm">
                        <input type="text" formControlName="ProductNameCtrl">
               <input type="text" formControlName="ProductSUKCtrl">

                       <input type="text" formControlName="ProductStatusCtrl">
                      <input type="text" formControlName= "ProductTypeCtrl">
                       </div>

    //For Checking whole form

    <pre>{{productForm.status | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{productForm.value | json}}</pre>


    How to check the inner form group status .

    <pre>{{productForm.productInnerForm.status | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{productForm.productInnerForm.value | json}}</pre>



    In component howw to check that

    this.productForm.get('productInnerForm').valid which shows undefined
```

Comment: Could you share your code in stackblitz ?

Comment: this is a demo stackblitz of sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-value-changes-49392097-qzxunj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a getter method for your inner form group:

```
get productInnerForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.productForm.get('productInnerForm') as FormGroup;
}
```

And then use it in your component class or the template:

In the class component: `console.log(this.productInnerForm.value);`

In the template: `{{productInnerForm.status | json}}` or `{{productInnerForm.value | json}}` etc.

You can also get access to the inner form group without use `get('...')` method:

`this.productForm.controls['productInnerForm'].value` or `this.productForm.controls['productInnerForm'].status` etc.

I've forked your sb example and added this example, [check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-value-changes-49392097-1ktmpp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments, could you please explain why we need get accessor here

Comment: In angular `FormGroup` class inherits from `AbstractControl` class, which has a method `get` - it simply retrieves a child form group or control given the control's name. You can check [official docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) on for more details on this.